# Installing python 32-bit in 64-bit machine which has python 64-bit (must coexist)

Tags: python, linux, installation, redhat, rhel

Running Linux RHEL7, how can I install 32 bit version of python in 64-bit machine without eliminating the 64-bit python. 
How do I ensure their respective dependencies are not broken after install ?

Comment: you want multiple versions of python..you will need a version manager ...check out  this one https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Comment: or virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper

Comment: does pyenv handle the case Im mentioning, not just the different version for the same target architecture? I thought pyenv is suitable if you want to run python 2.7 and python 3, not incompatible file type. Now, how can i install 32-bit version of python from a website link.